# Excel VBA のinternetexplorer.applicationを使用してhtml内の特定のクラス内の値を順に取得したい

Tags: html, css, vba

たとえば以下の様なhtmlがあり 
"class2"のdiv内のspan内の値(d,e,f)を順に取得するには 
どのようにすればいいのでしょうか？

```
<div class="class1">
<span>a</span> 
<span>b</span>
<span>c</span>
</div>
<div class="class2">
<span>d</span>
<span>e</span>
<span>f</span>
</div>
```

思いつき試したことは以下のコードのように 
"class2"のdivオブジェクトを探して見つかれば 
そのオブジェクトに対し同様の処理を行うということですが 
これでは値(a,b,c)も取得されてしまいうまくいきませんでした。

```
For Each obj1 In objIE.document.all.tags("div")
    If obj1.classname = "class2" Then
        For Each obj2 In obj1.document.all.tags("span")
            debug.print "span " & obj2.innertext & "->" & obj2.innertext
        Next
    End If
Next
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 実際に試していませんが、`span`を基準に`obj2.parentNode.classname = "class2" then ... End If`のように親ノードのクラスを確認すればいいかと思います。

Comment: こちらの方法で解決いたしました。 ご回答ありがとうございました。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/73334

Answer (score 1):

IE8以降であれば[`querySelectorAll`メソッド](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304115(v=vs.85).aspx)が使えます。

> "class2"のdiv内のspan

をCSSセレクターで表現すると `div.class2 span`となるので

```
For Each span In objIE.document.querySelectorAll("div.class2 span")
    debug.print "span " & span.innertext
Next
```

でしょうか。

Comment: こちらの方法で解決いたしました。
ご回答ありがとうございました。